# Using itext7 how to set special font like cyrilic or windows-1250

Tags: character-encoding, itext

If you have to render text written in Cyrillic or with any special characters like č, š, ž, ö, ç iText simply ignore that character. For example, text written in Russian or Ukrainian language is totally empty in generated PDF file. Any ideas? Thank you

Only what I've found so far is "translate" text to Latin characters, but it is really difficult if someone has to read (pronounce) the original text.

Comment: which fonts are you using? can you share your code?